# Error when calling container.BuildUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to inject dependencies into aspx codebehind using BuildUp, but it intermittently throws an error saying "X is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping"

I build my container in the global.asax. Then I created a basepage that all pages inherit from. Overriding the OnPreInit method, I do the following:

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var accessor = context.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;

        if (accessor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var container = accessor.Container;

        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No container found.");
        }

        container.BuildUp(this as T);
```

"this" is the page that is inheriting from BasePage.  I then use the Dependency attribute to decorate all dependencies in the actual aspx.cs that I want injected. If I do a clean and run it, it works fine. But if I do a refresh or the screen is triggered to refresh, it blows up with the error above.

Not sure what it's problem is. Maybe it doesn't like BuildUp being called twice.

More detail.

The type "X" is one of my custom interfaces. This is just a sample project I am doing to test something, but it looks like so:

```
public class BusObjectA : IBusObjectA
```

So it's pretty straightfoward.

In my sample aspx page, I have the following that I am trying to resolve via the BuildUp call:

```
 [Dependency]
 public IBusObjectA BusinessObjectA { get; set; }
```

Container creation:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(x => x.Namespace != null && x.Namespace.Contains("InjectionTest")),
                    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                    WithName.Default,
                    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
                     t => new InjectionMember[]
                    { 
                        new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
                        new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()
                    });
```

Comment: A couple of questions - what is type X that is throwing an error? Is it your custom interface? How it is specified on the page - as a property\constructor? And how your X is registered in the container?

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Comment: `ContainerControlled` means that `BusObjectA` will be singleton. maybe the issue is related to object lifetime? so it cant create it in the second time. Try to play with RegisterType parameters, maybe they are affecting it.

Comment: Good thought. But they all seem to have the same problem. I think it might just be something weird with things getting stuck in memory running from VS. Anytime I stop debugging and then start again, it blows up. But if stop, do a rebuild, run again, it's fine.